# Elementary set theory - show a function is surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

A question from my homework im currently trying to solve and can use a push in the right direction.

**Definition**: let $F(X)$ be the set of all functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$

Let $\phi: A \to B$  a function from set $A$ to set $B$, and let $\psi:F(B) \to F(A)$ be a function from $F(B)$ to $F(A)$ defined by: for all $f \in F(B)$, $\psi(f)=f \circ \phi$

Show that:

1) if $\phi$ is injective, then $\psi$ is surjective. Meaning for all $f_A \in F(A)$ there is an $f_B \in F(B)$ such that $\psi(f_B)=f_A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi$ is injective then <s>the inverse</s> a section $\phi^{-1}$ exists. Given a $f_A \in F(A)$, pick 
$$ f_B = f_A \circ \phi^{-1} $$
and see what happens `;-)`

**Remark:** As Oria noticed in the comment below, it's not formally correct to talk about $\phi^{-1}$. What we need, instead, is just a section (or a left inverse) of $\phi$, i.e. a map $g:B\to A$ such that $g\circ \phi = id_A$ (but not necessarily $\phi \circ g = id_B$).

Since $\phi$ is injective, it is always possible to find such a section. Note that $g$ is sometimes called $\phi^{\leftarrow}$.

Comment: I don't think this is true. By injective I mean that if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$. if $f^{-1}$ exists, then that means that f is bijective, not merely injective. IE if $f$ is injective but not surjective, $f^{-1}$ is not a function since it has elements in the domain that don't have an image

Comment: You are formally right, sorry I was being a bit sloppy. I edited my answer accordingly